# .startswith using multiple variables

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements, read-write, startswith

I am doing a project for school where I am making a cinema management system but I am a bit rusty with writing to/ reading from text files.

I have a list called `lineStarters` which contains string values "seatA", "seatB" etc etc.

later on in the project I use the line:

```
if line.startswith item in lineStarters and if "False" in line:
  line = line.replace("False","True")
```

This gives a syntax error.

To solve this I already tried a really long conditional statement. This didn't work either.Also it just wouldn't look good for my teacher.

tldr how would i go about using .startswith with multiple variables in Python.

Many thanks.

So I have a file called seatStatus which follows the format:
seatA:False for each line. Say the cinema would have 10 seats there would be 10 line going from seatA to seatJ. lineStarters is an array with all of the starters of lines e.g seatA,seatB (for validation). False would mean that the seat is not booked so it would be like this by default until changed so for the applicable seats it would replace False (unbooked) to True (booked). Hope that makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Is not clear from your statement what is your purpose, please add input and expected output to make it clear.

Comment: I tried to explain it better in the post. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check if your line starts with any of the `seatA`, `seatB`, etc, you can use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

```
if any(line.startsWith(item) for item in lineStarters) and 'False' in line:
```

Comment: I think this was what I was after. Thanks mate.